# What facility does Eclipse offer to run programs that were not included in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been posed with this question:

> What facility does Eclipse offer to run programs that were not included in Eclipse?

I can't find this question, or an answer to it, anywhere in a search engine... could someone please explain?

Comment: A plugin, or external program? And what do you mean _that were not included in Eclipse_, where should they be included in this sense?

Comment: That's the way the question was addressed. I didn't word it in that way. That's why I'm asking for information since I have no idea what this question is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse offers the Rich Client Platform (Eclipse RCP) which allows for the creation of plugins which can be used within the Eclipse platform. Eclipse itself is a collection of core plugins which may be referenced as dependencies of new plugins.

Comment: Great information! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That probably means the Eclipse Plugin facility, where you can run programs *inside* Eclipse, as if it were a part of the Eclipse software.